# Is it possible to make HtmlHelper extension method available to only those views with specific type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, extension-methods, html-helper, generic-method

I'm trying to implement my own paging for IEnumerable collections. So, I have a class called PagedList. I'm done with the class itself, I just need to write an HtmlHelper extension method that will render the actual pages. This would be the simplest way to go (at least I can think of):

```
public static MvcHtmlString Paginate<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel>,string url){
      //do the stuff here
      return new MvcHtmlString("Hi");
}
```

But, is it possible to make this method available ONLY in those views that are strongly typed to PagedList?

Comment: From what I can find on Google this is possible, yes, but I'm yet to see any confirming snippets of code.

Answer (score 3):

While @Ehsan Sajjad's answer is correct, I've found a neater way to accomplish this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Paginate<T>(this HtmlHelper<PagedList<T>> helper,string url){
    .......
}
```

I've tried and it really works. But there might be some other implications that I cannot think of at the moment, so any comments or corrections are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can put [constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) on method so that it can only be called on specific types, for Example `IEnumerable<PagedList>`, `PagedList<TModel>` or `PagedList` if you want, it depends on what Type of model you want, and also depends on implementation of your `PagedList` class:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Paginate<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper,string url) where TModel : IEnmerable<PagedList> {
  //do the stuff here
  return new MvcHtmlString("Hi");
}
```